# Control working directory within a function that is aborted in R

Tags: r, performance, output

I have a function that does a lot of repetitive calculations and at some point, it exports results in a working directory that is created by the function. A scheme of the function looks like this:

```
fun <- function (..., path){
# 1. create directory specified in the path argument
# 2. set directory from 1. as a working directory via setwd () function
# 3. do calculations
# 4. as 3. proceeds, the function exports results (several lists) in the new working directory
}
```

Sometimes, it happens that I need to abort the function at the stage 3. (e.g. after the function already created and set the working directory and possibly exported the part of the results to working directory).

**Question**: Is there a possibility to code a function so if it is aborted manually at stage 3, the function will set the working directory as it was before execution of the function (e.g. system default working directory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [on.exit()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/on.exit.html)

So in the beginning of the code, store the working directory with `home_dir <- getwd()`, and directly after that call `on.exit(setwd(home_dir))`. Hope this helps!

---

Example:

```
testfun <- function()
{
  home_dir <- getwd()
  on.exit(setwd(home_dir))
  setwd(dirname(getwd()))
}

getwd()

testfun()

getwd()
```

The both `getwd()` statements will return the same working directory, because although it is changed in testfun to `dirname(getwd())`, it is reset by the `on.exit()` call in `testfun.`